# Not able to get element by Xpath in Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

HTML Section :

```
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item k-state-focused" data-index="0" id="6609432f-2fd2-49c1-95df-6a330acecca0">admin</li>
```

Here the Xpath which I am trying :

```
 driver.findelement(by.xpath("//li[text()=//li[. = 'admin']"));
```

But getting exception :

**invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //li[text()=//li[. = 'admin'] because of the following error:**

**SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//li[text()=//li[. = 'admin']' is not a valid XPath expression.**

Exact look at UI and HTML code :

[image]

That field is auto complete.ID is changing dynamic of that element so I can not use id here to find element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XPath expression is not syntactically correct, there is an extra `[`, fix it:

```
//li[text()='admin']
```

Or, you may use `.` to refer to the text of the current node:

```
//li[. = 'admin']
```

Comment: Thanks for respond , I just tried your given solution and getting some closer error, I updated question , Can you please take a look.

Comment: @HelpingHands yup, but you are still trying an invalid expression `//li[text()=//li[. = 'admin']`. Try the `//li[. = 'admin']`. Thanks.